# c# WinForm globalizacion y localizacion de aplicacion

Tags: c#, windows-forms, localización

Estoy programando en c#, WinForm, intentando localizar mis aplicaciones.

elegi 6 idiomas (es-ES, pt-PT, en-US, fr-FR, de-DE, it-IT)

por un tema de velocidad en el ingreso de informacion numerica e elegido el punto decimal como punto decimal (es el que esta en el pad numerico de los teclados a la derecha).

y para las fechas elegi dd-mm-aaaa pues al ingresarlas ofrezco la fecha actual y la persona solo digita lo diferente, o sea si lo diferente es el dia solo escribe el dia y da enter, en cambio si el dia no fuera lo que esta al principio tendria que ubicarse y luego escribirlo, como lo que mas cambia son los dias, luego los meses y al final el año, elegi este formato.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo r = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");

r.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

r.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = r;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = r;
```

Instale la herramienta Resx Resource Manager

Tengo un proyecto donde estan todos los Form comunes a las diferentes aplicaciones y que se llama DllCommons

En cada proyecto tengo el proyecto principal y un proyecto DllDatosPropios

por lo que voy a tener: DllCommons.resources.dll, DllDatosPropios.resources.dll y proyecto.resources.dll ubicados en carpetas: en, es, de, it, fr, pt

los programas los tengo estandarizados con

TareasPrevias - creo base de datos, respaldos, reviso que todo este bien

FormInicio - usuario, clave y en caso de tener varias empresas se elije o se crea

FormMenuPrincipal - aqui estan todos los procesos organizados dentro de un menu

cada formulario se abre y cierra, en el caso de inicio y menu principal se puede volver para atras

mi consulta es la siguiente:

estas lineas son las correctas ?

las tengo en program.cs y cuando entro el FormInicio y FormMenuPrincipal se redibujan correctamente.

pero si selecciono en FormInicio el idioma y las vuelvo a ejecutar no se redibuja ningun formulario

es necesario reiniciar la aplicacion cuando se cambia el idioma ?
mediante codigo se consigue que los formularios se rellenen ?

en determinados controles como ser los ComboBox debo llenarlos con informacion segun el idioma

cual seria la forma de indicarle donde esta el texto que tiene que utilizar ?

anteriormente cuando habia un solo resource yo hacia esto:
`this.Text = StringResources.formMenuPrincipal;`

agregue esta linea para poder obtener la traduccion de un texto

`ResourceManager rm1 = new ResourceManager("DllCommons.resources.dll", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

luego trate de obtener la traduccion de "bSalir.Text"

`string awtexto = rm1.GetString("bSalir.Text", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);`

el archivo de recursos es "DllCommons.resources.dll" pero c# trata de buscarlo en "DllCommons.resources.dll.resources"

segun este error que me da

System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "DllCommons.resources.dll.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "DllCommons" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'

cual seria la correcta sintaxis de esta linea ?

`ResourceManager rm1 = new ResourceManager("DllCommons.resources.dll", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`